# Перевести mysql запрос в laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

есть запрос на mysql

```
SELECT *
            FROM `rooms`
    WHERE `hotel_id` = $hotel_id
    WHERE `people` = $people
    WHERE `id` NOT IN (
                SELECT `room_id`
            FROM `orders`
            WHERE `hotel_id` = $hotel_id
            WHERE `date_from` < $date_to AND `date_to` > $date_from
```

как записать его в ларавел?

пробую так, но какой-то бред

```
 $hotel_id = $request->hotel_id;

        $rooms = DB::table('rooms')
                    ->where('hotel_id','=', $request->hotel_id)
                    ->where('people','>=', $request->people)
                    ->whereNotIn('id',function($query,$hotel_id,$to,$from) {

                        $query->select('room_id')->from('orders')
                        ->where('hotel_id','=', $hotel_id)
                        ->where('date_from','<', $to)
                        ->where('date_to','<', $from);

                    })
                    ->orderBy('rooms.id', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: [гуглить политика партии мешает?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46384639/12593651)

Comment: исправил в ответе,но выдает ошибку Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Front\BookingController::App\Http\Controllers\Front\{closure}(), 1 passed in /home/e/extremje/hotel/hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 323 and exactly 4 expected

Comment: сравните свой вариант с тем что по ссылке - найдите отличия...

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через subquery

```
$users = DB::table('rooms')
            ->where('hotel_id', '=', $hotel_id)
            ->where('people', '=', $people)
            ->whereNotIn('id', DB::table('orders')
                ->select('room_id')
                ->where('hotel_id', '=', $hotel_id)
                ->where('date_from','<', $to)
                ->where('date_to','>', $from);
            )
            ->get();
```